# Why aren't all of the URLs being downloaded?

Tags: javascript, minecraft

Currently working on NuovoLauncher and have been charged with working on the core workings of the project. For those unaware, NuovoLauncher is in essence a Minecraft Launcher, although the vision is to take it much further.

However, I am struggling on the following: Getting all the Minecraft natives to download, which are needed to launch the game.

Here's the code I have so far

```
async function getNatives(version) {
asset_json = require(descriptorFolder + `/${version}.json`);
libraries = asset_json.libraries;
lib_url = [];
urls = []

for(lib of libraries) {
    try {
        lib_url = Object.values(lib.downloads.classifiers);
        for(jobj of lib_url) {
            partial_path = new URL(jobj.url).pathname;
            full_path = path.join(nativesFolder, partial_path);
            createFolderRecursive(partial_path);
            await utils.file.httpsGet(jobj.url, full_path);
        }
    } catch(error) {
        ;
    }
    
}}
```

Where the descriptor file is: https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/ed5d8789ed29872ea2ef1c348302b0c55e3f3468/1.7.10.json

I know the code grabs all of the urls, its just not downloading all of the files.

Any ideas much appreciated
-Connor

Comment: So what is not working? Have you tried rethrowing (or at least logging) the errors instead of ignoring them?

Comment: Yes, the errors are when certain things aren't defined, like `lib.downloads.classifiers` so I just ignore the error knowing that's what's being thrown.

Now to more specifically answer your question, some of the natives are being downloaded, but not completely and others not at all